# Text not wrapping around div

Tags: html, css, css-float, dreamweaver

I'm working on an `HTML` file in `Dreamweaver` and am having issues with the text wrapping around a div tag. The div has `float: right` associated with it which is what all other sites I researched suggested. I have also tried it in two separate div tags rather than one div inside the other and that also did not work. My end game is to have the box float right at the bottom of the div with text wrapping around it on the left side. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

```html
<div class="text" style=" width:600px; float:left;">xcea volo ipis cusda dolori aut prerum faciet autempo riberum dendipidebis sum cusdaer eriatem ut harchicilit, ea aut fugit, velliciuntur autem. Itati aturio quae cus. Officti ad molor si ut volor ant. Nat ut dolum que velestium fugitae magnima quo consecus necteca eperchicium volor restiae. Et aperspicabo. Ulparunte ant ipiders peleceprovit fugiae ereptassi ratur sed molor rerenis nam, volor ad qui siminus ipit quam eos repelibearum exeri dolorundus. Atur? Ost, sint aut vendae di inctotatur? Quid endempor antendi tiatur sitia num harum aut quo blaudae ptatinieni aliqui to dit qui quo beatia comnit rest quatur alignis tiosapelenis es mincid millesc ipsus, occustius si rem et re sit ad quo int. Vollecabor res molupta sequatus, conse voloreptat voluptatatem faces il iunt, corum faceribusant earumquate pel essum a que por alis ide volorrum ditio dolorecus, sunt latem sim dest vit et a dolo et odiae voluptam ipsum es suscit que comniandam, atum fugit facest, volum aperi doluptae quiatia del in posam hit, utemporuntia conse suntet ulluptat. Em doluptatis etur aut verepti oratur simusaepudam nus rene idero ducillam eium rem eictus volorerum, ea cus que ducimus ius as re con pra
<div class="box" style="width:250px; height:300px; float:right; background-color:#A495C3">Content for class "box" Goes Here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="text" style=" width:600px; float:left;">xcea volo ipis cusda dolori aut prerum faciet autempo riberum dendipidebis sum cusdaer eriatem ut harchicilit, ea aut fugit, velliciuntur autem. Itati aturio quae cus. Officti ad molor si ut volor ant. Nat ut dolum que velestium fugitae magnima quo consecus necteca eperchicium volor restiae. Et aperspicabo. Ulparunte ant ipiders peleceprovit fugiae ereptassi ratur sed molor rerenis nam, volor ad qui siminus ipit quam eos repelibearum exeri dolorundus. Atur? Ost, sint aut vendae di inctotatur? Quid endempor antendi tiatur sitia num harum aut quo blaudae ptatinieni aliqui to dit qui quo beatia comnit rest quatur alignis tiosapelenis es mincid millesc ipsus, occustius si rem et re sit ad quo int. <div class="box" style="display: inline-block; width:250px; height:300px; float:right; background-color:#A495C3">Content for class "box" Goes Here</div>Vollecabor res molupta sequatus, conse voloreptat voluptatatem faces il iunt, corum faceribusant earumquate pel essum a que por alis ide volorrum ditio dolorecus, sunt latem sim dest vit et a dolo et odiae voluptam ipsum es suscit que comniandam, atum fugit facest, volum aperi doluptae quiatia del in posam hit, utemporuntia conse suntet ulluptat. Em doluptatis etur aut verepti oratur simusaepudam nus rene idero ducillam eium rem eictus volorerum, ea cus que ducimus ius as re con pra

</div>
```